# What is the difference between isBLANK and isNULL in salesforce?

Tags: java, null, salesforce

I'm confused about `isBLANK` and an `isNULL` in salesforce. I think both are same, but they are not same. What  is   the difference between isBLANK and an isNULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [documentation](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISNULL):

> Use ISBLANK instead of ISNULL in new formulas. ISBLANK has the same
>   functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. Salesforce
>   will continue to support ISNULL, so you do not need to change any
>   existing formulas.